# Embedding NavigationController When Using Sidemenu CosmicMaterial

Tags: swift, xcode, cosmicmind

I am using CosmicMaterial (http://www.cosmicmind.io/material) for implementing Sidemenu or a.k.a drawer menu. I've read the documentation and how to run the sample projects of this cool library. I was able to see the demo of Sidemenu of CosmicMaterial.

One problem though is that I am having a hard time figuring out how to embed a navigation controller in Sidemenu.

My code in Appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Get view controllers from storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeTableViewController") as! HomeTableViewController
        let sideViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SideTableViewController") as! SideTableViewController

//        var navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootNavigationController") as! NavigationController
//        
//        var sideNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SideNavigationController") as! NavigationController
//        
//        navigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: homeTableViewController)
//        sideNavigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: sideViewController)
//        
//        
        // Configure the window with the SideNavigationController as the root view controller
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = SideNavigationController(rootViewController: homeTableViewController, leftViewController: sideViewController)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

And here's my layout in storyboard. All ids of each xibs have been set.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before. I just figured out that I am assigning the navigonController improperly. See the codes below:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Get view controllers from storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootViewController") as! RootViewController
    let sideViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SideViewController") as! SideViewController

    let navCon2 = NavigationController(rootViewController: sideViewController)
    let navCon = NavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)

    let sideNavigationController = SideNavigationController(rootViewController: navCon, leftViewController: navCon2)
    sideNavigationController.enabledLeftTapGesture = true
    sideNavigationController.enabledLeftPanGesture = true
    sideNavigationController.enableHideStatusbar = false

    // Configure the window with the SideNavigationController as the root view controller
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = sideNavigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Note that you have to set the properties correctly of the SideNavigationController. And unhide the statusbar, or else you'll experience annoying bug when showing the side menu.

Cheers!

Comment: I wrote this article for 3-damn-hours just for this problem :) http://www.prettyitgirl.com/2016/05/implementing-sidenavigationcontroller.html